# Gunicorn and Nginx: Can't access from remote client

Tags: linux, django, http, nginx, gunicorn

I have setup my django application through ssh using gunicorn and nginx.

Here is my procedure:

1. I start the web app using gunicorn:
   `sudo gunicorn --workers=2 -b :8888 tutorial.wsgi:application`
2. I start nginx: `sudo service nginx start`

    Here is the conf file:

   ```
     server {
           listen 8002;
       server_name wiser.omk.dk;
           access_log /home/pikachu/access.log;
           error_log /home/pikachu/error.log;
           location /static {
               root /home/pikachu/django_rest_sandbox_omk_prod/tutorial;
           }

           location / {
               proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
               allow all;
           }}
   ```
3. Running `curl -i 127.0.0.1:8002` from localhost returns `HTTP 200` (Works as expected)
4. Running the command `<remote domain>:8002` from remote gives `"Connection refused"`

Looking into the iptables `sudo iptables -L -n | grep 8002`:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:8002
```

If I run a tcpdump on the server: `sudo tcpdump port 8002 -vv`

TCPDump output:

```
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
23:42:35.357580 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 16513, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    x1-6-f8-1e-df-e2-a1-2f.cpe.webspeed.dk.52181 > 10.32.0.104.8002: Flags [S], cksum 0xe91d (correct), seq 1169831423, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 965849406 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

Why does the server not respond from remote requests?

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same issue

Comment: If I recall correctly all package on port 8002 was dropped by iptables. The solution was to add a rule to iptables. I recommend to read this article about adding new rules to iptables: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands

Comment: try to start with `-b 0.0.0.0:8888`